# Rails 3.2.3 - twitter like pagination or endless pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I went through many articles regarding twitter like paging using AJAX for Rails and now I'm a little bit confused. I think I didn't find yet what I was looking for.

I have a web site, it shows the photos and has a table layout.

```
<table>
  <% i = 0
     tdCount = 3
     @photos.each do |p|
       if i % tdCount == 0%>
          <tr>
      <%end%>
      <td>
              <%=image_tag(p.source , {:width => 240})%>
      </td>
      <%if i % tdCount == (tdCount-1)%>
          </tr>
      <%end%>
      <% i += 1 %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

As far as I'm concerned it's quite difficult to use any "pageless" solution since I have a table  layout. If not so, which one should I use? Which one is more modern than others and works good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never Ending page is nothing but the pagination in which you wont have links at the bottom like normal pagination rather your next page would get appended at the bottom of your current page when the scroll reaches at the bottom.

Please refer [rails cast endless][1]

[1]: http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page?view=comments  For better understanding.

I have created it in Jquery ajax though in the link it is done using Javascript.

Comment: How do I use this regarding my page? Where should I insert photo-partinal?

Comment: Is their Pagination present in your page? Do you have links like 
`previous 1 2 3 next` at the bottom ?
I am asking this because, U will be creating endless page if u have enough page content which does not fit in your one page and u need pagination links.

Comment: It's not on my page since I don't know how to use it. Obviously I have enough items.

Comment: use gem will_paginate first for pagination. After then you will get an idea and watch episode 114 of rails_cast.
I have provided the link above.

Comment: I don't need to do that when browser is scrolled to the bottom. I need to do that by clicking the link. Why can I do that?

Comment: If u'll do that when browser is scrolled to the bottom , only then it is called as endless page  and in your question u referred to endless pagination.
otherwise if you simply want to provide links for each page you can use the gem `will_paginate`. Its too simple to use.